# Dynamically creating buttons and assigning click actions

Tags: python, pyside2, qpushbutton

I'm trying to practise by making a Pokedex. I'm trying to dynamically create a list of buttons inside of an OVBoxLayout based on the response from an API call. The list of buttons is generated correctly however, none of the buttons work, code below:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from app.pokeapi_client import PokeApiClient


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setup_styles()

        self.pokemon_list_data = PokeApiClient().get_pokemon_list(limit=9)
        self.setWindowTitle("Pokemon")
        self.resize(1000, 800)

       # create main layout
       main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

       # build list layout and populate with labels
       self.pokemon_list_layout = QVBoxLayout()
       self.populate_pokemon_list_layout()

       # add list layout to main layout
       main_layout.addLayout(self.pokemon_list_layout, 1)

       self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def populate_pokemon_list_layout(self):
        for pokemon in self.pokemon_list_data['results']:
            button = QPushButton(pokemon['name'])
            button.clicked.connect(self.print_this)
            self.pokemon_list_layout.addWidget(button)

    def print_this(self):
        print("hello world!")

    def setup_styles(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QWidget {
                background: red;
            }
            QPushButton {
                color: white;
                background: blue;
                border: 1px solid white;
            }
        """)
```

The button.clicked.connect() doesn't appear to be assigning the function to each button, anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Why do you point *The button.clicked.connect() doesn't appear to be assigning the function to each button*? Also what package provides app.pokeapi_client ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont get what you mean by your comment? I want each dynamically created button to execute print_this() on click. That PokeAPIClient is completely irrelevant to the issue, it just provides some data.

Comment: 1) okay, now I understand what you are saying, 2) If it is irrelevant then replace it with a dummy list to avoid confusion, 3) provide an MRE, for example remove the dependency on "app.pokeapi_client" and add where you use MainWindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MRE with your code :

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui

DATA = {'results':[{'name':'pikka'}, {'name': 'dracofeu'}, {'name': 'mewtwo'}]}

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pokemon_list_data = DATA #Emulation data
        self.setWindowTitle("Pokemon")
        # self.resize(1000, 800)

        # create main layout
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        # build list layout and populate with labels
        self.pokemon_list_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.populate_pokemon_list_layout()

        # add list layout to main layout
        main_layout.addLayout(self.pokemon_list_layout, 1)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


    def populate_pokemon_list_layout(self):
        for pokemon in self.pokemon_list_data['results']:
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(pokemon['name'])
            button.clicked.connect(self.print_this)
            self.pokemon_list_layout.addWidget(button)


    def print_this(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender.text())


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
test = MainWindow()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

Here is the result : 
[image]
As you can see I didn't change anything (except imports and the sender in the print_this method) but it works. I think you have a problem somewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you recommend any good resources for learning PySide AlexLaur?

Comment: Hey @decprog ! I can recommend stackoverflow because the community is really cool. And when you have a question, very often, a people before you had the same question^^. You can read the docs with all stuff for pyside here : https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/ (it helped me a lot at the start). On youtube you have some tutorials too. I hope it can help you for learning PySide. Maybe there are other resources, but I don't know.